# Difference in adjective phrase

Tags: grammar, adjectival-phrases

What is the difference between

- There is something **wrong with** him

And

- There is something **wrong about** him

Answer (score 1):

*Something wrong with him* usually implies that he is unwell or distressed.

*Something wrong about him* suggests that the speaker is suspicious of him or uncomfortable in his company.

Comment: Yes, 'wrong with' points to 'something naturally wrong', whereas 'wrong about' puts a suspicious background to it.